# IBM Worklight - How to customize the connectOnStartup failure dialog

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

It possible to customize the Error Alert which popups while we set the connectOnStartup=true. I don't want my users to click on "Details" from that alert and view the details of the error message. I want to customize that alert with my custom message and action.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. In addition to using `connectOnStartup` property in initOptions.js, also use the `onConnectionFailure` property:

   ```
   var wlInitOptions = {
       connectOnStartup : true,

       // # The callback function to invoke in case application fails to connect to Worklight Server
       onConnectionFailure: function () { 
           WL.SimpleDialog.show(
               "foo",
               "bar",
               [{text: "button",
                handler : function() {alert("button pressed");}
               }]
            );
           // optionally add more logic here
       },
       ...
       ...
   ```
2. Do not use the `connectOnStartup` property. Instead, use `WL.Client.connect` to connect to the server when appropriate. For example, in `wlCommonInit()`

   ```
   function wlCommonInit() { 
       WL.Client.connect({ onSuccess: success, onFailure: failure});
   }

   function success() {
       // ...
   }

   function failure() {
       WL.SimpleDialog.show(
           "foo",
           "bar",
           [{text: "button",
             handler : function() {alert("button pressed");}
           }]
      );
       // optionally add more logic here
   }
   ```

Comment: I want to completely suppress this alert. I don't want my users to know the connection to WorkLight Server is failed in connectOnStartup. If i remove the custom alert, it always shows the post default alert. Please help me on this case... Thanks.

Comment: Well, did you try in initOptions.js onConnectionFailure : function() {} // empty function (or just a WL.Logger.debug or something like that)?

Comment: Empty function give default alert that i have posted in this thread.  Will try to add WL.Logger.debug inside the function and post you. Thanks.

Comment: i have just posted you an email with the screenshot of the same. Please check and let me know your input on the same.

Comment: Please don't change your original question. You asked a question and I answered it. If you have an additional question - create a new question rather than distorting the past.

Comment: I thought both are same issue. But just find out its not same issue. My Apologies. I will create a new question. Thanks.